# Order record by departure time [PHP,MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql

I want order a query by departure time (increasing). I use:

```
$query = "SELECT station,hdeparture FROM train WHERE number = '".$id_train."' ORDER BY hdeparture";
```

But it seems don't work because there is no ordering.

What's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: is hdeparture a date\time field type?

Comment: Yes, It is. It is a time field

Comment: is there any result at all?

Comment: create an [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) example for us

Comment: What exact type is it set to ? Can you show us sample data ? I can't reproduce it with the following fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f386/1

Comment: Is this concatenating is good, can we use like this       $query = "SELECT station,hdeparture FROM train WHERE number = '$id_train' ORDER BY hdeparture";

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/325bc

Comment: Yes though I think the single quotes may trigger an implicit cast if the field is not of a character / string type.

Comment: opartenza is hdeparture sorry!

Comment: Zan, I have tried your query but nothing the problem remain

Comment: Well in this case number is a unique primary key so you will only have 1 row and no sort can be applied to a single row.

Comment: So have I to remove the primary key?

Comment: no, just don't limit what you want to return to 1 row

Comment: No. I'm just not sure what you are trying to do here. If you select a train station / trip / whatever by its unique primary key, you will always have only 1 row. As Dragon said, don't use that WHERE clause because it will always limit it to 1 row if it's applied to the unique primary key.

Comment: is it a language issue or a logic issue, why did you think you can 'sort'  a single row?

Comment: but can i do something like: $query="SELECT ..." and than $query2 = "SELECT a FROM ".$query." ?

Comment: yes, but what ever you are trying to do could probably be done with ha single querry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are limiting the content to a single row by filtering your data by a field which only contains unique values. The query will either return 1 or 0 rows and the sort will not do anything.

Here is your SQLFiddle modified where you can see the trips in order of departure. Only the filter on `numero` was removed.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/325bc/6

Comment: but can i do something like: $query="SELECT ..." and than $query2 = "SELECT a FROM ".$query." ?

Comment: Yes you can have subqueries. Also, as a general principle it is best to think of these issues alone and then combine them. What I mean is that you should not think of SQL problems in terms of PHP strings. Think of the SQL queries that you want to do and then figure out how to include them in your PHP code. This is in conformity with the layering design principle.